# Evaluate $\iint_S (y-z) dy dz+(z-x)dzdx+(x+y)dxdy$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate 
$$
\iint_S (y-z) dy dz+(z-x)dzdx+(x+y)dxdy, 
$$
where $S$ is the portion of the surface $x^2 +y^2-2x+z=0$, for which $z\geq 0$.

I do not know where to start. In fact this is the first time I see $\iint_S dxdy $ being used in 3 dimensions instead of $\iint_s dS$.

Comment: Use [The Divergence Theorem](https://www.math24.net/divergence-theorem/)